# NOT using reference to object (javascript)

Tags: javascript, express

The below :-

```
req.session.user = doc[0];
req.session.user.password = null;
```

Makes `doc[0].password = null`!

What do i do to prevent that?

Edit: Where `doc[0] = { name: 'sangram', e-mail: 'abc.in', password : 'pwd' }`

Comment: You will have to clone `doc[0]` and use new instance that won't affect the original.

Comment: @ShadowWizard how? code please.

Comment: @closure its an object.

Comment: @SangramSingh can't really do it without you posting what is `doc[0]` exactly. In JavaScript there's no native "clone()" method. How it's defined?

Comment: @ShadowWizard added in edit.

Comment: How about req.session.user.password = req.session.user.password || null;

Comment: doc[0] IS a "reference" (pointer), regardless of your headline. Only primitive types are stored "directly", variables holding objects are "pointers" (internally)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way to do so is to copy every property of an object:

```
req.session.user = {};
for (var key in user) {
  if (key !== 'password') req.session.user[key] = user[key];
}
```

If `user` is a mongoose document, you probably should convert it to plain object first:

```
req.session.user = {};
var json = user.toObject();
for (var key in json) {
  if (key !== 'password') req.session.user[key] = json[key];
}
```

But the easiest way to do what you want is to adopt some helpful library like [underscore](http://underscorejs.org/) or [lodash](http://lodash.com/):

```
req.session.user = _.omit(user.toObject(), 'password');
```

Answer (score 2):

For simple case of simple objects, I wrote a small helper function:

```
function ShallowClone(obj) {
    var clone = {};
    for (var key in obj)
        clone[key] = obj[key];
    return clone;
}
```

Usage in your case:

```
req.session.user = ShallowClone(doc[0]);
req.session.user.password = null; //won't affect doc[0] password
```

[Live test case](http://jsfiddle.net/N64Zq/). (with dummy object)

Answer (score 0):

You can't prevent this. The `user` property is set to that object `doc[0]`. Later you edit `.password` property of that newly assigned object. If you want to keep the `password` separately you have to assign `doc[0]` to another object.

```
req.session.user = {};
req.session.user.doc = doc[0];
req.session.user.password = null;
```

Here is a method for cloning/extending an object:

```
var extend = function() {   
    var process = function(destination, source) {   
        for (var key in source) {
            if (hasOwnProperty.call(source, key)) {
                destination[key] = source[key];
            }
        }
        return destination;
    };
    var result = arguments[0];
    for(var i=1; i<arguments.length; i++) {
        result = process(result, arguments[i]);
    }
    return result;
};
```

And its usage:

```
var original = { value: "bla" };
var duplication = extend({}, original, { newProp: "test"});
```

Comment: but in your code above, i do not get req.session.user = doc[0] in everything else except password.

Comment: Yes, that's how JavaScript works. You can't change the value of some variable, change it and expect to see a different behavior.

Comment: i want to clone the doc[0] object in the first statement.

Comment: Cloning an object in JavaScript is not an easy thing. It depends of the object. If you have a lot of nested properties you may not receive what you want. I updated my answer with a function which I used.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend updating or changing your question in the future.

[What is the most efficient way to deep clone an object in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/122102/most-efficient-way-to-clone-an-object)
[How do I correctly clone a JavaScript object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/728360/most-elegant-way-to-clone-a-javascript-object)

Crockford provides a very good answer [here](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=PXa2bby0oQ0C&pg=PA80&lpg=PA80&dq=javascript%20crockford%20shallow%20copy&source=bl&ots=HItmp6w3jI&sig=WbcIRmVVEQ9t6ziX0dtdA5YwbFE&hl=en&sa=X&ei=hWuUUuClKsyxhAeezYDYDA&ved=0CFoQ6AEwBQ#v=onepage&q=javascript%20crockford%20shallow%20copy&f=false)